# Quiet git remote update?

Tags: ruby, git

I am trying to quiet the `git remote update` command in my Ruby script.

I used the `--quiet` flags of other Git commands like `git checkout [branch_name]`.

For some reason Git doesn't have that flag when doing a `git remote update`. Does anybody know any other way?

I have also tried to put the output to `/dev/null` like `git checkout [branch_name] < /dev/null`.

I am open to any Ruby or command line suggestions.

Comment: `git checkout [branch_name] < /dev/null` won't "quiet" a command. `git checkout [branch_name] > /dev/null` will.

Comment: Thanks must have been confused!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want output to go to `/dev/null`, use:

```
git checkout [branch_name] > /dev/null
```

or

```
git checkout [branch_name] &> /dev/null
```

The way you wrote it, you are expecting input from `/dev/null`.